# Export menu links with features

Tags: 7, routes, features

I'm trying to export menu links with features but it saves the node id in the feature, but obviously the nid is different in dev, test and production.

I can't use UUID because nodes are created in every environment.

Is there a way to export menu links with alias and not with nids?

Comment: A new module was created for menu links features integration, https://www.drupal.org/project/features_menu_uuid. This may not address the exact use case of the original question, but might be useful for others finding this from a search.

Answer (score 3):

http://webwash.net/tutorials/import-and-export-menus-menu-import-module-drupal-7 shows how to use http://drupal.org/project/menu_import which uses path aliases instead of UUID.

I think this would work.